# Excel VBA - Range(Find().Adress).Row

Tags: excel, vba

I have googled and struggled with this for hours now.

I have a Control workbook, that pulls data from a varied amount of other workbooks (the Control workbook also creates the other workbooks and saves the names and dir of said workbooks so that they can be called later)

This piece of code is the problem.

```
Application.DisplayAlerts = False
Application.ScreenUpdating = False

Declare_Sheets

Dim SearchresultROW
Dim Searchresult As String
Dim complexrow As Integer
Dim CurrSheet As Worksheet
Dim Stype As String

Dim startROW As Integer
Dim endROW As Integer, SearchCOL As Integer, OffROW As Integer
Dim PDATArange As Range, CDATArange As Range
Dim Dateyear, Datemonth, datetest As String

Stype = WSRD.Range("B11")

'Find complex to work with
complexrow = WSSS.Range("F7")
WSSS.Activate
SearchresultROW = Range(Cells(7, 15), Cells(complexrow, 15).Find(Callsheet).Address).Row
Searchresult = WSSS.Cells(SearchresultROW, 15).Offset(0, 1)


Application.DisplayAlerts = True
Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

The below code is the problem extract

```
complexrow = WSSS.Range("F7")
WSSS.Activate
SearchresultROW = Range(Cells(7, 15), Cells(complexrow, 15).Find(Callsheet).Address).Row
Searchresult = WSSS.Cells(SearchresultROW, 15).Offset(0, 1)
```

**1st problem**
I cant get the find() to work without activating worksheet - WSSS
Declare_Sheets gets run at the start which declares WSSS, this works everywhere else in my code, but not with this find().

**2nd problem**
The code below compiles and finishes, BUT - It does not return the correct data.

This code calls starts the macro

```
Cancel = True
Dim Calsheet As String
If Target.Column <> 1 Then Exit Sub
Calsheet = Target.Value
Call Call_Readings(Calsheet)
End Sub
```

There are currently 2 possibilities

[image]

I double click on Casper Tcomp 4.
Callsheet = "Casper Tcomp 4" - *Which is correct (target of the double click)*

Complexrow = "9" - *Which is correct (this will increment as new sheets are added)*

SearchresultROW = "7" - *This is wrong, it should be 8*

I have tried adding LookAt:=xlWhole and LookIn:-xlValues, doesnt change a thing

Comment: Where is `Callsheet` defined? You should check you've found something before trying to access properties etc to avoid errors.

Comment: Thanks, Callsheet is defined as a string, in "Sub Call_Readings(Callsheet as string)", I neglected to paste that first line of the code in the above, thanks for pointing that out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code without `.Activate` would look something like below. Note that **every** `Range`, `Cells`, `Rows` or `Columns` object needs to be referenced with the correct Workbook/Worksheet:

```
complexrow = WSSS.Range("F7")

'try to find something
Dim FindResult As Range
On Error Resume Next 'next line will error if nothing is found
Set FindResult = WSSS.Cells(complexrow, 15).Find(What:=Callsheet, LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt:=xlWhole, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, MatchByte:=False)
On Error GoTo 0 'always re-activate error reporting!


If Not FindResult Is Nothing Then  'check if find was successful
    SearchresultROW = WSSS.Range(WSSS.Cells(7, 15), FindResult).Row
    Searchresult = WSSS.Cells(SearchresultROW, 15).Offset(0, 1)
Else  'if nothing was found show message
    MsgBox "nothing found.", vbCritical
End If
```

Note that if using the [Range.Find method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.range.find) you need to check if something was found before you can use the result of `Find`. Otherwise it will throw an error. Also note that the documentation of `Find` says that …

> The settings for `LookIn`, `LookAt`, `SearchOrder`, and `MatchByte` are saved each time you use this method.

So if you don't define them each time using `Find` it will use whatever was used last by either VBA or the user interface. Since you have no control about what was used last by the user interface I highly recomment to define them everytime using `Find` or you will get random results.

Also note that `Callsheet` is not defined in your code yet, so check that.

Comment: Thank for the assist, I had to make 2 changes, replaced `Set FindResult = WSSS.Cells(complexrow, 15).Find(What:=Callsheet, LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt:=xlWhole, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, MatchByte:=False)` with  `Set FindResult = WSSS.Range(WSSS.Cells(7, 15), WSSS.Cells(complexrow, 15)).Find(What:=Callsheet, LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt:=xlWhole, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, MatchByte:=False)`

Comment: and `SearchresultROW = WSSS.Range(WSSS.Cells(7, 15), FindResult).Row` with `SearchresultROW = WSSS.Range(WSSS.Cells(7, 15), WSSS.Cells(complexrow, 15)).Find(What:=Callsheet, LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt:=xlWhole, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, MatchByte:=False).Row`

Comment: @CasperDuPlessis Well that change contradicts completely with the idea that I explained. If you use `Find` directly in a longer statement this will easily throw errors if nothing is found. The idea is always to set the result of find to a variable `Set FindResult = Range().Find` and nothing more to be able to check if it was successful or not `If Not FindResult Is Nothing Then {successful} Else {not successful}`. If you put `Find` together with other statements like `Find().Row` this is without checking it (and it will crash if nothing is found).

Comment: The problem with your code was that this `Set FindResult = WSSS.Cells(complexrow, 15).Find(What:=Callsheet, LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt:=xlWhole, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, MatchByte:=False)` doesnt provide a range for the Find(), it simply provides one cell - WSSS.Cells(complexrow, 15)....Or am I missing something?

Comment: @CasperDuPlessis but the range is generated here `SearchresultROW = WSSS.Range(WSSS.Cells(7, 15), FindResult).Row` using the result of find `FindResult`.

Comment: So I understand what you mean, but this part I dont get if `Set FindResult = WSSS.Cells(complexrow, 15).Find(What:=Callsheet, LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt:=xlWhole, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, MatchByte:=False)` complexrow = "9" and Callsheet is not in Cells(9,15) then it will fail.....it should be checking for Callsheet in Range(Cells(7,15),Cells(9,15)) bucause Callsheet could be in any one of those Cells....

Answer (score 1):

```
Application.DisplayAlerts = False
Application.ScreenUpdating = False

Declare_Sheets

Dim SearchresultROW
Dim Searchresult As String
Dim complexrow As Integer
Dim CurrSheet As Worksheet
Dim Stype As String
Dim FindResult As Range

Dim startROW As Integer
Dim endROW As Integer, SearchCOL As Integer, OffROW As Integer
Dim PDATArange As Range, CDATArange As Range
Dim Dateyear, Datemonth, datetest As String

Stype = WSRD.Range("B11")

'Find complex to work with
complexrow = WSSS.Range("F7")
On Error Resume Next 'next line will error if nothing is found
Set FindResult = WSSS.Range(WSSS.Cells(7, 15), WSSS.Cells(complexrow, 15)).Find(What:=Callsheet, LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt:=xlWhole, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, MatchByte:=False)
On Error GoTo 0 'always re-activate error reporting!

If Not FindResult Is Nothing Then  'check if find was successful
    SearchresultROW = FindResult.Row
    Searchresult = WSSS.Cells(SearchresultROW, 15).Offset(0, 1)
Else  'if nothing was found show message
    MsgBox "NO WB FOUND.", vbCritical
End If
```

This solved the problem, thanks for the assistance Pᴇʜ

Comment: Just a note: You should declare row counting variables as `Long` because Excel has more rows than `Integer` could handle. And `Dim Dateyear, Datemonth, datetest As String` only declares `datetest` as `String` and the first 2 as `Variant`. If they contain year and month (numeric values) I recommend `Dim Dateyear As Long, Datemonth As Long, datetest As String` otherwise `String` instead of `Long`.